# AWS Appsync - How to protect the API Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

```
  const APPSYNC_HOST = "host.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
  const APPSYNC_REALTIME_HOST =
    "host.appsync-realtime-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
  const APPSYNC_API_KEY = "da2-key";

  function encodeAppSyncCredentials() {
    const creds = {
      host: APPSYNC_HOST,
      "x-api-key": APPSYNC_API_KEY,
    };
    const b64Creds = window.btoa(JSON.stringify(creds));

    return b64Creds;
  }

  function getWebsocketUrl() {
    const header = encodeAppSyncCredentials(APPSYNC_HOST, APPSYNC_API_KEY);
    const payload = window.btoa(JSON.stringify({}));

    const url = `wss://${APPSYNC_REALTIME_HOST}/graphql?header=${header}&payload=${payload}`;

    return url;
  }

  function startSubscription(websocket) {
    const subscribeMessage = {
      id: window.crypto.randomUUID(),
      type: "start",
      payload: {
        data: JSON.stringify({
          query: `subscription NotificationSubscription {
                  onCreateNotification {
                    content
                    id
                    time
                  }
                }`,
        }),
        extensions: {
          authorization: {
            "x-api-key": APPSYNC_API_KEY,
            host: APPSYNC_HOST,
          },
        },
      },
    };
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify(subscribeMessage));
  }

  const url = getWebsocketUrl();

  const websocket = new WebSocket(url, ["graphql-ws"]);

  websocket.addEventListener("open", () => {
    websocket.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        type: "connection_init",
      })
    );
  });

  websocket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    message = JSON.parse(event.data);
    switch (message.type) {
      case "connection_ack":
        startSubscription(websocket);
        break;
      case "start_ack":
        console.log("start_ack");
        break;
      case "error":
        console.error(message);
        break;
      case "data":
        console.log( message.payload.data.onCreateNotification );
        break;
    }
  });
```

Using the following code I can successfully subscribe to the graphql endpoint and get real time data. My concern is, I will deploy it on production soon but here API Key is exposed and without API Key authentication doesn't work... How do I protect it? What should be alternate option here to use authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html), which is a service designed specifically for this use-case.

> AWS Secrets Manager helps you manage, retrieve, and rotate database credentials, application credentials, OAuth tokens, API keys, and other secrets throughout their lifecycles. Many AWS services store and use secrets in Secrets Manager.

Comment: Thanks, I am very much new to this and documentation looks zibber zabber to me; lol

Comment: It's very simple. You store a secret as a key value. The key is how you obtain it, the value being your API key. You called the API to obtain it and pass it into your API call.

Comment: So I guess it's an async request to get the API Key on the fly... right?

Comment: It's not necessarily Async because you need the key to pass into subsequent requests.